# Test Environment Maps for Robot Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was wondering if there is a database of different environment maps for testing robot navigation in ROS. In particular, I'm looking for an open space environment map without narrow corridors and many obstacles.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192626/test-environment-maps-for-robot-navigation/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-09-13**:
What format are you looking for? Just a map, i.e. yaml/ppm?

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-13**:
Yes yaml/pgm files would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're looking to test navigation with fake maps (i.e. environments in simulation), you should probably try using the gazebo simulator. I'm not sure if any of the gazebo environments come with pgm maps ready to plugin, but running a gmapping cycle with a teleoperated robot would be a good opportunity to test the robot's control/sensor setup.

A 2D map is as much a product of your robot's sensor setup as it is of the environment.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-13**:
Thanks. I'm using rviz because it provides many visualization tools to debug sensors and the navigation module. That's why I'd rather test work on 2D maps for now just because of rviz.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-13**:
The map alone won't do you any good, you need the simulated sensor feedback from the environment if you want to run tests. This is what gazebo provides (as a simulator), alongside rviz (a visualizer). There is also this [2D simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/stdr_simulator) which comes with some maps.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-14**:
Thanks a lot Paul. I think I was confused about rviz as a visualizer and gazebo as a simulator. Now it's ,more clear to me.